# vb.net - LinkedResource with question mark in path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-email

I am trying to create an HTML email with an attached image using asp.net VB.

The trouble I am having is that the image is stored as binary code in a table rather than on the server.

I have the following code:

```
Dim myHeader As New LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("/Handler.aspx?id=237"), "image/jpeg")
```

I know it's the question mark in the path that's causing the problem. Does anyone know a way around this??

Answer (score 1):

`Server.MapPath` will only return the path of the 'Handler.aspx' file, it won't be able to run the logic in the file that is returning the image.

I think your only way around it would be to  extract the image from the DB in your code (maybe reuse/call the logic from 'Handler.aspx') and then attach it to your email.